# Wordpress install on LEMP -> NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: wordpress, ssl, nginx

On my server I have 4 services running (my web page, plex...). I wanted to install WP on this one as a dev server.

All my previous services got their SSL certificate thanks to Let's Encrypt.

I set up WP for http only so I don't know why my browser tells me :

`Your connexion is note private [...] NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

my nginx file :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name w.gfelot.xyz www.w.gfelot.xyz;

    root /var/www/wp/;
        index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

Any idea ?

EDIT:

Thanks to Richard Smith I update my server block

```
server {
       listen           80;
       listen           [::]:80;
       server_name      www.w.gfelot.xyz w.gfelot.xyz;
       return           301 https://w.gfelot.xyz$request_uri;
       }

server {
       listen           443 ssl http2;
       listen           [::]:443 ssl http2;
       include          snippets/ssl-gfelot.conf;
       include          snippets/ssl-params.conf;

       server_name      w.gfelot.xyz;
...
```

But I got the same result.

Comment: Do you have HTTP Strict Transport Security including sub-domains?

Comment: how can I check that ?

Comment: I just add a certificat for my WP subdomaine and I have the same error.

Comment: I check and nope I don't have `add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";` anywhere in one of my server block

Comment: I have this header sorry. It was inside an include and not in the server block.

Comment: So instead of connecting to `http`, the browser is trying `https` and finding the default server for port 443 (which may just be the first one). Which explains the CN mismatch.

Comment: I edit my question. I setup my block for HTTPS bt I got the same.